# Update multiple templates meteorjs

Tags: meteor

In my template I have the following code

```
{{#each cards}}
    ...
            <h4>Time left {{timeLeft validUntil}}</h4>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
    ....
{{/each}}
```

in the database I have an example card like this

```
{groupId: groupId, posted: new Date(),validUntil:moment().add(24,'h').toDate()});
```

The template helper

```
Template.groupDetails.helpers({
timeLeft: function(validUntil){
    var diff = moment.duration(moment().diff(validUntil));
    return [diff.hours()*-1, diff.minutes()*-1, diff.seconds()*-1].join(':')
}
});
```

I then have created a setIntervall that uses the created event on the template

```
Template.groupDetails.created = function() {
Meteor.setInterval( updateTimers, 5000 );
};
```

I have the function updateTimers:

```
function updateTimers() { };
```

I have testes multiple things like adding a timeLeft int to the database, but it feel like waste to have it in the database when I already have created and validUntil already there.

How can I update the timeleft inside all my cards from the function called every 5 seconds?

I have tried looking into workarounds like this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/1172

But this feels like an awful hack

Answer (score 0):

The solution you linked is not really a hack but exactly the way Meteor works (although you shouldn't use `Session` in this case). Instead of explicitly rerendering the template, you specify dependecies, invalidate the depending computations, and let Meteor and Blaze take care of the rendering.

In your example, you could create a [`Tracker.Dependency`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_dependency) like this:

```
var timerDep = new Tracker.Dependency;
```

The helper has to depend on `timerDep`:

```
timeLeft: function() {
  timerDep.depend();
  …
}
```

Finally, you invalidate the helper's computation every five seconds:

```
function updateTimers() {
  timerDep.changed();
}
```

That way, your helper will be rerun either when `validUntil` changes or when the timer expires.